# Django models created twice?

Tags: python, django

Why my Attribute models are being saved twice in my database? Weird...

Here's my view code:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
@transaction.atomic()
@reversion.create_revision()
def add_item_type(request, id_item, id_item_type):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=id_item)
    item_type = ItemType.objects.get(id=id_item_type)

    item.status = Item.DEPLOYED # Set to phase deployment
    item.save()
    for a in item_type.attribute_types.all(): # Create all attribute skeletons to item
        Attribute.objects.create(name=a.name, description=a.description, type=a.attr_type, item=item)
    ctx = {'item':item, 'item_type':item_type}
    return render_to_response('des/item/add_item_type.html', ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**EDIT:**

When I look at my database (postgres) I found that my view's loop is called two times (not saving twice in the same loop), or my view is called twice. I don't know why. I'm pretty sure this isn't a loop problem because in my db, Attribute class is saved like this.

```
id - name 
1 - fly 
2 - sit 
3 - run 
4 - fly 
5 - sit 
6 - run
```

Any ideas why? 
To understand my code, see ItemType as a class and AttributyType as the attributes of the class ItemType, and Item is the instantiation of ItemType and Attribute is of AttributeType.

Comment: well, you have a loop there. why don't you check in the shell the result of `ItemType.objects.get(id=id_item_type)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved my question by assigning a unique=True value in the Attribute model (Attribute.name) so there's no same Attribute on the same Item class. What I did is a "patch" but doesn't solve the real problem, the view being called twice.

Comment: You should use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)